# Destructuring assignment in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

The is code works fine by destructuring the object and assigning the variables,

```
const { allowNegative, decimal, precision, prefix, suffix, thousands } = this.options;
```

But when i try with `this` operator like below it throws an error:

```
{ this.tabConfig, this.searchUiConfig, this.gridUiConfig } = CONFIG;
```

where **CONFIG** being a JSON. Error being ***[ts] Declaration or statement expected*** on the assignment operator(=).

Is there a better way of doing than this:

```
 this.tabConfig = CONFIG.tabConfig;
 this.searchUiConfig = CONFIG.searchUiConfig;
 this.gridUiConfig = CONFIG.gridUiConfig;
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it with the following syntax:

```
({ prop: this.prop } = obj);
```

Here I'm using a [deep object matching](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingDeepMatching)

```
var obj = { propIwantFromObj: 'foo' };
var { propIwantFromObj: whereToStoreValue } = obj;
```

On the left part you will say which property you want to get from the object and on the right side you are going to say where to store the value. So in this case a new variable called `whereToStoreValue` will be created with `foo` value.

```
var obj = { propIwantFromObj: 'foo' };
var whereToStoreValue = obj.propIwantFromObj;
```

That can be used to store values on `this` (or other object), but you need to wrap it around parenthesis because of the `.`. For some reason this hack allows you to use `.`.

If you don't use the parenthesis you will get syntax errors (it won't work in pure JS either).

Example:

```js
const CONFIG = {
  tabConfig: 1,
  searchUiConfig: 2,
  gridUiConfig: 3,
};

class Foo {
  bar() {
    ({ tabConfig: this.tabConfig, searchUiConfig: this.searchUiConfig, gridUiConfig: this.gridUiConfig } =  CONFIG);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();

console.log(foo.tabConfig);
console.log(foo.searchUiConfig);
console.log(foo.gridUiConfig);
```

Comment: works greattt...Can you briefly explain what is happening?

Comment: Sure, hope that helps.

Comment: This is great, I liked `({ prop: this.prop } = obj);`. Thank you very much.

Comment: NOTE for anyone looking for this, this does not work on declarations.